# asp.net web service: converting json objects

Tags: c#, asp.net

i receive this type of json in parameter in my c# project :

```
{ "results": [
{
  "FormID": 1,
  "GateLetter": "B",
  "ID": 1,
  "FINNumber": "757",
  "GateNumber": "345",
  "FlightNumber": "1234",
  "ShiftID": 1,
  "LSAName": "",
  "AirlineCode": "QK",
  "LSAEmpID": "Another",
  "FormName": "DFW Loader",
  "createdAt": "2012-01-17T17:40:11.533Z",
  "updatedAt": "2012-01-17T17:40:11.533Z",
  "objectId": "sJS5iVXPot"
},
{
  "FormID": 1,
  "GateLetter": "",
  "ID": 1,
  "FINNumber": "",
  "GateNumber": "",
  "FlightNumber": "123",
  "ShiftID": 1,
  "LSAName": "",
  "AirlineCode": null,
  "LSAEmpID": "",
  "FormName": "DFW Position",
  "createdAt": "2012-01-17T20:58:17.932Z",
  "updatedAt": "2012-01-17T20:58:17.932Z",
  "objectId": "Ni8KspVjwA"
},
{
  "FormID": 1,
  "GateLetter": "a",
  "ID": 1,
  "FINNumber": "",
  "GateNumber": "12",
  "FlightNumber": "123",
  "ShiftID": 1,
  "LSAName": "",
  "AirlineCode": "AC",
  "LSAEmpID": "trent",
  "FormName": "DFW Position",
  "createdAt": "2012-01-17T23:31:11.686Z",
  "updatedAt": "2012-01-17T23:31:11.686Z",
  "objectId": "FXciW6zM6Q"
}
```

But it is not a string, my question is : how can i transport this into a string or var
to be able to deserialize it afterwords...

into this type :

```
string data = @"[{""ShiftID"":""2"",""EmpName"":""dsdsfs""},{""ShiftID"":""4"",""EmpName"":""dsdsfd""}]";
```

this type can be deserialize perfectly but not the first one!

Comment: What type of param is it, if not a string?  byte[]?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that appreciation is shown via upvotes and accepted answers (checkmark). If you have any questions, please refer to the [FAQ], I especially suggest to all newcomers to review the [Ask]

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you are looking for is actually a third party: [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/). I do not know about this translating as you directly mentioned, but it will deal with the deserialization into one of your POCO's

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the first one can be deserialized just fine:

```
public class FlightInfo
{
  public string FormID {get;set;}
  public string GateLetter {get;set;}
  //... 
  public string objectId {get;set;}
}

public class FlightContainer
{
    public List<FlightInfo> results;
}

JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var deserializedObject = js.Deserialize<FlightContainer>(yourJsonString);
```

Now you can access your FlightInfo elements like so:

```
FlightInfo firstItem= deserializedObject.results[0];// by index
```

Or you can iterate through them

```
foreach(var item in deserializedObject.results) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.FormID);
}
```